# how to declare a Class for Attachment on a Case Object

Tags: apex, case, blob

How to Pass Blob file_body and file_Name

```
public void uploadFile(Blob body, String name, String reqEndPoint){

          String boundary = 'fddfed232323';
          String header = '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+file_name+'"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';
          String footer = '\r\n--'+boundary+'--';              
          String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
           //Blob file_body= ''  ;
          // String file_name= '';
          String endpoint = 'https://xxx/rest/api/2/issue/{JiraId}/attachments-addAttachment';
          while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='))
          {
           header+=' ';
           headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
          }
          String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body);
          String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));

          Blob bodyBlob = null;
          String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
          if(last4Bytes.endsWith('='))
          {
               Blob decoded4Bytes = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(last4Bytes);
               HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
               tmp.setBodyAsBlob(decoded4Bytes);
               String last4BytesFooter = tmp.getBody()+footer;   
               bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(last4BytesFooter)));
          }

} 
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. What is the issue you're facing? Asking "how to do _____" and posting code doesn't provide enough detail to enable this community to help you

Answer (score 0):

Going on minimal information, I assume you're asking how to substitute file_body for body and file_name for name. You would simply do the following:

```
public void uploadFile(Blob body, String name, String reqEndPoint){

      String boundary = 'fddfed232323';
      String header = '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+name+'"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream'; // change file_name to name
      String footer = '\r\n--'+boundary+'--';              
      String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
      String endpoint = 'https://xxx/rest/api/2/issue/{JiraId}/attachments-addAttachment';
      while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='))
      {
       header+=' ';
       headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
      }
      String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(body); // change file_body to body
      String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));

      Blob bodyBlob = null;
      String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
      if(last4Bytes.endsWith('='))
      {
           Blob decoded4Bytes = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(last4Bytes);
           HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
           tmp.setBodyAsBlob(decoded4Bytes);
           String last4BytesFooter = tmp.getBody()+footer;   
           bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(last4BytesFooter)));
      }

} 
}
```